# Load an image from aws s3 bucket to django application

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I made a django app that stores notes of different semesters and branches and I want to display the profile image of the uploader of the post right next to their name in homepage of my website. I am using my staticfiles directly from the S3 bucket

The notes that the users upload is stored in the notes/models.py whereas the user's profile and their profile image is stored in users/models.py

What I want to do is in `home.html` (below) use something like,
`{% static post.uploader.profile.image.url %}` but suddenly it does not work.

Settings.py

```py
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME='django-XXXXX'
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "ap-south-1"
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = "s3v4"
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

# s3 static settings
AWS_LOCATION = 'staticfiles'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AWS_LOCATION}/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

# s3 public media settings
PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION}/'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'django_project.storage_backends.PublicMediaStorage'

# s3 private media settings
PRIVATE_MEDIA_LOCATION = 'private'
PRIVATE_FILE_STORAGE = 'django_project.storage_backends.PrivateMediaStorage'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

notes/models.py

```py
class Notes_Model(models.Model):
    """Store notes of different branches and semesters."""
    
    uploader = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2500)
    branch_choice = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=branch_choices, default='cse')
    file_semester = models.IntegerField(choices=semester_choice)
    file = models.FileField()
    syllabus = models.TextField(max_length=200, default='No Syllabus Availibe Yet')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("notes-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

users/models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.svg', upload_to='profile-pics')
    
    def __str__(self):
       return (f'{self.user.username} Profile')

    def save(self):
        super.save()

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

home.html

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}
  <div>
  {% for post in posts %}
      <article class="media content-section">
      <img class="rounded-circle article-img" <!--this src is posing the issue -->src="{% static post.uploader.profile.image.url %}" width="60" height="60" style="margin-right: 30px">
        <div class="media-body">
            <p class="mr-2 text-capitalize">{{ post.uploader }}</p>
            <small class="text-muted font-italic">{{ post.date_posted }}</small>
          <div class="article-metadata">
          </div>
          <h2><a class="article-title text-info text-capitalize" href="{% url 'notes-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
          <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
        </div>
      </article>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

xml from aws s3 bucket says that no key is present but it is present in the bucket.

```xml
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>staticfiles/</Key>
<RequestId>960CD372E7128E16</RequestId>
<HostId>
90tvY+TT6FkefEheQXtuOLv5T8fCvJsDzIOBpam8inz4GGdhpb9QXrkToDCl/3yN+69tJoUUYQo=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

**Url that gets returned is: https://django-xxxxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/staticfiles/**

whereas it should be

**Expected url that gets returned: https://django-xxxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/staticfiles/profile.jpg**

Problem:
[Top left part of the image is not being rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDYsP.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `{% static %}` templatetag, for something that *is not a static file*. It's a media file. The value of `post.uploader.profile.image.url` should be the actual URL to the image as a *media* asset. Passing that URL to `{% static %}` tries looking up the URL as the name of a *static* asset, which is why you get the `NoSuchKey` error.

Comment: okay, I agree that it's a media file but for different users even if when I use `{{ post.uploader.profile.image.url }}` which then again does not work either.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Is there an image uploaded for that profile, meaning the image is not `None`? Does the `default.svg` default exist? Is the bucket for media files properly configured?

Comment: does not work means, that the image is not loaded from the S3 bucket to the frontend of my website. The cause of the problem seems to be `<img src=" {{ post.uploader.profile.image.url }}">` I for one am unable to set the right path in the `img`. Do you have any insight on this? and yes the S3 bucket is properly configured.

Comment: One other thing: `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` is defined twice. The second one wins, so it looks like you don't have the buckets configured properly, as you are not using the `PublicMediaStorage` class and are instead using the (I assume) base class `S3Boto3Storage`.